# What is the usage of "was become of..."

Tags: meaning, phrases

In the following sentences

> "What was become of Peter?"

Source: [Charles Haddon Spurgeon](http://www.spurgeon.org/s_and_t/peter.php), quoting [Acts 12:18 KJV](https://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/Acts-12-18/).

> What became of my second Brother I never knew any more than Father or Mother did know **what was become of me**.

Source: *[Robinson Crusoe](http://web.stanford.edu/class/history34q/readings/crusoe/robin1.html)*

What is the usage of *was become of...*?

Comment: No, [what was become of](https://www.google.com/#tbm=bks&q=%22what+was+become+of%22) is completely correct, if very old-fashioned.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old-fashioned usage meaning

> What happened to

or

> What was the fate of

Compare the *Oxford English Dictionary*:

> ***become of*** (after ‘what’) was used formerly in sense of ‘come out of, result from,’ but has also taken the place of ‘where is it become,’ etc., in 1b, **in reference to the later locality, position, or fate of a person or thing** (emphasis mine).